# How to write test cases for .NET

Tags: automated-testing, .net

I want to create a test case, for this code, in .NET:

```cs
public static string GetCaseClient(Case cCase)
{
        try
        {
            string cClient = "";
            if (cCase.CaseParties != null && cCase.CaseParties.Count > 0)
            {
                var caseParty = cCase.CaseParties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttorneyEFMId == cCase.FilingAttorneyEFMId);
                if (caseParty != null)
                {
                    cClient = caseParty.PartyRole == CasePartyRole.Person ? string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", caseParty.FirstName, caseParty.MiddleName, caseParty.LastName) : caseParty.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    var casePartySelf = cCase.CaseParties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttorneyEFMId == "Self");
                    if (casePartySelf != null)
                    {
                        cClient = casePartySelf.PartyRole == CasePartyRole.Person ? string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", casePartySelf.FirstName, casePartySelf.MiddleName, casePartySelf.LastName) : casePartySelf.Name;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cClient;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
}
```

Please help me?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: What do you want to learn from your test?

Answer (score 1):

I would read up on howto create .Net unit-tests: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs

Afterwards try to create unit-tests for each possible inputs and verify expected outputs. Try to cover each if and its possible states/branches. Use [code coverage tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) to check you are hitting the full function.